# Adding authentication at project creation or with Connected Services

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to build ASP.NET Core 2.1 web applications. When a project is first created, there is an option to add authentication. I can add "work or school" single org cloud authentication at that point.

There is also an option to add authentication through the project "Connected Services" by selecting "Authenticate with Azure Active Directory". This option seems to add more (and different) code than the first way to add authentication.

When would I use one vs. the other?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to research the many documents about app and Azure auth methods. This is otherwise a bit too broad for SO. e.g., https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I have read a lot of docs. I understand the authentication technology and have projects using authentication added in both ways. My specific question is since these two ways of adding authentication seem to create different code in the project, are there situations where you would use one way over the other? I'm sure that explanation might be in docs somewhere but I haven't found it yet. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, but we don't see any code here. Just a description of something you have done. The assumption is that an ASP app can use a number of different auth mechanisms, and one of those will be hosted by a connected service like Azure. Without knowing what "single org cloud auth" is, we can only guess that it is different that the OAUTH flavour provided by Azure. It will be different code because it is a different mechanism. One probably uses credentials, and the other probably uses tokens. But it's hard to know from this description.